# Change the font size of the equation in latex

Tags: equations, fontsize

How can i change the font size of both equation individually?

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
 % Change the font size
r_j &= 2 \\ 
&\quad + 4
\end{split}
\\
% Change the font size 
r_j = 2 + 4
\end{eqnarray}
```

I try \scalebox but i got some error. I try :

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\scalebox{.95}{
\begin{split}
r_j &= 2 \\ 
&\quad + 4
\end{split}
}
\\
\scalebox{.95}{
r_j = 2 + 4}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Please get in the habit of posting not code snippets but fully compilable examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some comments

- The second argument of `\scalebox` is in text mode by default. To treat it as math material, you need to surround the math material with `$` symbols.
- You can't have a `split` environment inside a scalebox. However, an `aligned` environment works.
- The `eqnarray` environment is [badly deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). Don't use it!! Instead, use either `align` or `gather`. In the code below, I use a `gather` environment as no alignment appears to be performed in your `eqnarray`-based example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "gather" and "aligned" environments
\usepackage{graphicx} % for "\scalebox" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\scalebox{1.33}{$
   \begin{aligned}
    r_j &= 2 \\ 
        &\quad + 4
   \end{aligned}$} \\
\scalebox{.75}{$
   r_j = 2 + 4$}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```